# Calling Vuex actions defined using square brackets (computer property names) in namespaced modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've seen many times other devs using computed property names to define actions & mutations names, eg.

```
export const SOME_ACTION = 'someAction'
```

And then:

```
[SOME_ACTION]({ commit }) { ... }
```

Which in turn lets you dispatch actions using this neat way:

```
this.$store.dispatch(SOME_ACTION)
```

Kinda feels like NgRX, which I like. But what about Vuex namespaced modules? Is there any way to dispatch actions neatly, providing only the SOME_ACTION var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone wondering how did I figure it out:

I've used createNamespacedHelpers from vuex to prepare the helpers first:

```
const { mapGetters, mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('some/nested/module')
```

Afterwards you can map 'em like that:

```
...mapActions([SOME_ACTION, SOME_OTHER_ACTION])
```

And call, for example, like this:

```
this[SOME_ACTION]()
```

Answer (score -1):

How does this work for you?

```
...mapActions({
  nsOne: 'namespaced/nsOne',
  nsTwo: 'namespace/nsTwo',
  nonNsOne: 'nonNsOne', 
  nonNsTwo: 'nonNsTwo'
})
```

and then call with

```
this.nsOne()
```